# Two variable derivative function mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, mathematical-optimization, education

I am trying to find the point where the partial derivatives are equal to zero.

The function I am analyzing:

```
f[x, y] := 3 xy - x^2 y^2;
```

The area it is restricted within: dom[x, y] := x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x + y <= 4;

The code I use:

```
Solve[D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}] == {0, 0}]
```

The error message I get is "5 is not a valid variable". I think that when i enter the code that mathematica doesnt understand that y is a variable, because x is blue and y is black in the mathematica code.

Is anyone familiar with this error?

Please tell me if you need any more information to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this,

```
f[x_, y_] := 3*x*y - x^2*y^2;

Solve[D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}] == {0, 0}]
```

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRri8.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRri8.png) Yes thats what I always have done :(

Comment: I by accident entered my answer to your comment in a new answer slot.

Comment: @KalleAnka Quit Kernel and then evaluate again

Comment: Sorry, what does that mean?

Comment: @KalleAnka Click on evaluation tab then scroll down to the `Quit Kernel` and click

Comment: omg thank you so much, is this something I have to do everytime?

Answer (score 1):

```
(* the following will work: *)
Clear[f, x, y]
f[x_, y_] := 3*x*y - x^2*y^2;
Solve[D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}] == {0, 0}]
(* the following will produce your error: *)
x = 5;
Solve[D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}] == {0, 0}]
(* Here is why the error occurs: *)
Trace@Solve[D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}] == {0, 0}]
```